# Derivative of $x\sin x$

Tags: calculus

Suppose: $f(x) = x\sin x$

What is the Instantaneous rate of change when $x=-9$

I know that the setup is:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

However I am not very familiar using trigonometric units (besides the standard $\frac{\pi}{3}$ etc. etc.) in a limit problem. How would I go about solving this? Do approximate values suffice or do I need exact values?

Comment: approximate values suffice

Comment: In the limit, approximations become "close enough," or at least as close to "close enough" as mathematicians allow.

Comment: @Amzoti We haven't gone over L'Hopital's Rule. I assumed I would have to do expansions to solve it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd *want* to obtain approximate values, unless you're "evaluating" the limit by plugging in a small nonzero number for $h$ or need them for further calculation. At first glance, the only way I see to get approximate values is to get the exact values first!

Answer (score 2):

The following should be clear enough to show the process.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

any way the Instantaneous rate of change when x=−9 is :
$$ \left. (x\sin(x))^{'} \right |_{x=-9}  = \left. \sin(x) \right |_{x=-9} + \left. x\cos(x) \right|_{x=-9} = \sin(-9)-9\cos(-9) $$

python gives an approximation of 7.788053871720336